Implementing a simple websocket client in spring boot listening to 2 different websocket endpoints - but they always start executing together
I have 2 websocket endpoints producing related messages:
"ws://localhost:8032/posts"
"ws://localhost:8032/comments"
Comments are guaranteed to be published after a referred post and there could be deletion events after which if there is a out of synch comment, it will result in an error.
I am trying to implement a simple client first without all the fancy stuff and while I am easily able to listen to one endpoint, listening to both at the same time makes my system behave in a weird way.
I have this config:

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfig {

    private static final String postUri = "ws://localhost:8032/posts";
    private static final String commentUri = "ws://localhost:8032/comments";

    private final PostHandler postHandler;
    private final CommentHandler commentHandler;

//    @PostConstruct
//    public void connectToWebSocketEndpoints() {
//        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
//
//        client.doHandshake(postHandler, postUri);
//
//        WebSocketClient client2 = new StandardWebSocketClient();
//        client2.doHandshake(commentHandler, commentUri);
//    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketConnectionManager postConnectionManager() {
        WebSocketConnectionManager manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(
                new StandardWebSocketClient(),
                postHandler,
                postUri);

        manager.setAutoStartup(true);

        return manager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebSocketConnectionManager commentConnectionManager() {
        WebSocketConnectionManager manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(
                new StandardWebSocketClient(),
                commentHandler,
                commentUri);

        manager.setAutoStartup(true);

        return manager;
    }
}

I want to initialise the comment client a bit later. But no matter what, both clients come into affect at the same time.
What I tried so far:

I tried adding dependentOn the first bean
added thread.sleep
Combined the beans into one bean for WebSocketConnectionManager and initialised them one by one
Tried to initialise the client inside @PostContruct

In all cases, the behaviour is the same - both connections are established at the same time and they process messages in a burst.
How can I implement 2 independent listeners on 2 different websocket endpoints ? After the initial delay in initialization, I am ok for them to work in parallel.
Bonus:
Just for testing purposes, I initialised the second client via an endpoint. This behaviour was fine when I controlled the startup of second client but after a bit, the out of synch nature of the messages started to result in a lot of errors. Should I be consuming these messages with a single listener ?

According to the Javadoc, setAutoStartup will 'Set whether to auto-connect to the remote endpoint after this connection manager has been initialized and the Spring context has been refreshed.'. What happens if you set manager.setAutoStartup(true); to false in commentConnectionManager()?

@LeeGreiner I also tried to remove auto start and use manager.start() but it has the same effect. As I understand, the default value is false.

Where in the client did you call manager.start()? What happens if you never call manager.start()?

@LeeGreiner I was calling the start() instead of setAutoStartup(). Nothing happens when I do not call start() or set autostart to true.

I thought you didn't want it to start at the same time as the other one. You said 'I want to initialize the comment client a bit later.' If you call start() later, manually after bean initialization, you will get what I thought you wanted. You could listen for the ApplicationReadyEvent and call start().

@LeeGreiner this is how I imagined that the start() method would work, but it is not working like that. If I use anything like DependsOn or even Thread.sleep to delay the start of the second listener, they both start at the same time only.

DependsOn and Thread.sleep() (assuming you are sleeping in commentConnectionManager()) are all being performed during bean creation. The effect will be the same as you have mentioned. Try running start() sometime after bean creation (ApplicationReadyEvent). If your main issue is the 'burstyness' and the order in which messages are processed, then we need to know more about how the messages are generated and the issue they are creating. How are the message bursts adversely affecting your client application?
